# Vectors in the Third Dimension

Tags: calculus, vectors

[image]

I am just beginning to learn about three dimensional vectors and I am not really sure how to go about this problem. I set r1=r2 but I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key fact is that if the lines intersect at a point $P$, then $P=r_1(s)=r_2(t)$ for some values of $s$ and $t$. (It doesn't have to be the *same* value of the parameter $t$ for each line; that's why I've changed the variable to $s$ for the first line.)

Therefore, you need $4s+9=-3t-2$ (from the first component) and $8=-3t-1$ (from the last component). So $t=-3$ (from the second equation), and hence $s=-0.5$. If you plug in $t=-3$ to the second line $r_2$, we get the point $(7,8,8)$. Plugging in $s=-0.5$ to the first line $r_1$ gives the point $(7,8,8)$. This confirms that $P=(7,8,8)$ is the point of intersection.

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely helpful and the correct answer. I feel a lot more confident with this problem. Thanks again!

Comment: The statement "The lines are guaranteed to intersect because they are not parallel" is only true in two dimensions, not necessarily the three dimensions of the question. It is trivial to find a counter example in higher dimensions where this statement doesn't hold.

Comment: @Daryl: you're right; I shouldn't answer questions this late at night. I'm deleting that part of the answer.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Other than that one statement, it was a good answer. :-)